# How to disable swiper js pagination clickable on state change?

Tags: javascript, svelte, swiper.js

How can i disable the click of swiper pagination on certain condition progammatically?

I added clickable flag in pagination object and tried to change is on a state(disableClick) change.

```
const pagination = {
  clickable: disableClick,
  renderBullet: function (index, className) {
    label = tabsName[index];
    return '<span class="' + className + '">' + tabsName[index] + "</span>";
  },
};
```

And added pagination to Swiper component.

```
<Swiper
  {initialSlide}
  {pagination}
  modules={[Pagination]}
  class="mySwiper"
>
  <slot />
</Swiper>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer if any one is looking for solution:
You can add `noSwipingClass` as a prop

```
<Swiper
  {initialSlide}
  enabled={!disableSwipe}
  modules={[Pagination]}
  class="mySwiper"
  noSwiping={disableSwipe}
  noSwipingClass={disableSwipe ? "swiper-slide" : ""}
>
  <slot />
</Swiper>
```